# Navigate particular page in pdf inside axacropdf control in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, process, navigation, axacropdf

I have stucking in my application. I have developing a pdf viewer application. I creating windows application with .net 3.5. In this application I have taken axacropdf control and took hyperlink 1 to 10 as page number. Now I want to show pdf file with that page inside axacropdf control when I click the particular page number hyperlink. for example I have pdf file with 10 pages. I have list of all pages like

```
Navigate to Page 1
Navigate to Page 2
Navigate to Page 3
Navigate to Page 4
Navigate to Page 5
.................. etc.
```

Now when I click on hyperlink **Navigate to Page 5** the pdf file open with page 5 in axacropdf file. Here is the code:

```
    //create process to open pdf file
                Process myprocess = new Process();
                myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "AcroRd32.exe";
                myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=" + y + "\" " + txtFileName.Text + " ";
                myprocess.Start();
```

I have googled about this but I found only open the pdf file with particular page outside of the application through process class.         But I want to open this pdf file in adobe pdf reader (axacropdf) control in c#.
Please give me suggestion or code.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this [API Ref](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf)

its going to be much easier they even have a method called SetCurrentPage on page 113 hope that helps.